# Skipping Diagonal Elements Within a Square Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, logic

Wrote a program to display a square matrix (ex: 5x5) and I am trying to count the total of the elements excluding the elements that lie within a diagonal line (from top left to bottom right & from bottom left to top right)

EX:

In a 5x5 matrix, only the `X`s would be counted

```
O X X X O
X O X O X
X X O X X
X O X O X
O X X X O
```

Thus:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

Total: 16
```

OR

```
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2

Total: 32
```

Here is my code

```
int calculateVal(int **mat, int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            if (isRightDiagonal(size, row, col) == true ||
                isLeftDiagonal(size, row, col) == true)
            {
                col++;
            }
            count += mat[row][col];
        }
    }
    return count;
}

bool isRightDiagonal(int size, int row, int col)
{
    return (col = abs(row - size)) ? true : false; 
}

bool isLeftDiagonal(int size, int row, int col)
{
    return (row = abs(col - size)) ? true : false; 
}
```

I tried using an if statement to check if the element is within a diagonal, and if so, skipping to the next element, but the output is wrong.

The test case I have been primarily using is a 5x5 of 1s like the example above; however, the total prints out as 10 rather than 16

Comment: Don't you mean `col == abs(row - size)` instead of `col = abs(row - size)`? (likewise for `row`)

Comment: Also using `col++` to skip to the next value may cause your program to read out-of-bounds. Use `continue` instead.

Comment: That did change the total of a 5x5 of 1s to 21, so that might have done something, If I put 'count += mat[row][col];' in an else{} it changes it to 18, but the output should be 16.

Comment: Also, one of your checks seems to be incorrect. To check if an element belongs to the main diagonal, it suffices to check if `row == col`.

Comment: It's confusing when you say "count" when you mean "sum".

Answer (score 1):

The tests for the diagonals are incorrect:

- an element is part of the left diagonal if `col == row`
- an element is part of the right diagonal if `size - 1 - col == row`

Furthermore, if the element is part of either diagonal, it should just be ignored, incrementing `col` is incorrect as it may make `mat[row][col]` refer en element outside the matrix, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
int calculateVal(int **mat, int size) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            if (col != row && size - 1 - col != row) {
                count += mat[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sample matrix with 1 for the entries you don't want to count (if you sum them instead of count then the value is not 0 then you know something is off).  You could use a similar crafted matrix to ensure that the the 16 entries you are interested in are counted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int matrix[][5] = {
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    };
    size_t sum = 0;
    const size_t n = sizeof matrix / sizeof *matrix;
    for(size_t r = 0; r < n; r++)
        for(size_t c = 0; c < n; c++)
            sum += (r != c && r + c + 1 != n) * matrix[r][c];
    printf("sum = %zu\n", sum);
}
```

If you don't like the non-branching style here is another way to express it:

```
            if(r != c && r + c + 1 != n)
                sum += matrix[r][c];
```